# How to select and get the path of file (like .txt or .apk file) in Android phone

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I use following code to get the path of image and video file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1); 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();  

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);  
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.i("PATH", "File path = " + cursor.getString(1));
        Filepath = cursor.getString(1);
        filepath.setText(Filepath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But it can not get the path of other file like the **.txt , .apk , .zip** or other format.

**How to get the path of file for other format?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this It worked For extracting .apk file path !!!

```
PackageInfo packageInfo;
AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
            packageInfo = appData.getPackageInfo();
```

and after this

```
// path
        path.setText(packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
```

Hope it will work for You !!!
Reply For any Queries.

Comment: it error at AppData , "AppData cannot be resolved to a type". I am in fragment not at Activity.